# Is it possible to add a Real Time Stock Tracker to a Salesforce home page?

Tags: visualforce-component, callout

Is it possible to add a Real Time Stock Ticker to a Salesforce home page using the following ticker symbols?

```
S&P 500 (^GSPC)
Dow Jones Industrial Average (^DJI)
NASDAQ Composite (^IXIC)
Russell 2000 (^RUT)
Crude Oil Aug 21 (CL=F)
Gold Aug 21 (GC=F)
Silver Sep 21 (SI=F)
EUR/USD (EURUSD=X)
Bitcoin USD (BTC-USD)
Treasury Yield 10 Years (^TNX)

APTS
PSEC
BRG
BHR
CIM
LAND
GAIN
GOOD
CMCT
GWGH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer would be yes. There is almost nothing you can not develop and put where you want.  I have never done this but no doubt there are many apis floating around out there to get just this sort of info. You would need to develop your own LWC etc that consumed that API and displayed the data to a user.

Comment: Thanks Brooks!  I assumed so. I appreciate your time.